# unix shell replace string twice (in one line)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I run a script with the param `-A AA/BB` . To get an array with AA and BB, i can do this.

```
INPUT_PARAM=(${AIRLINE_OPTION//-A / }) #get rid of the '-A ' in the begining
LIST=(${AIRLINES_PARAM//\// })         # split by '/'
```

Can we achieve this in a single line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use `${AIRLINE_OPTION#-A }` to remove `-A ` from the beginning, which is shorter and portable.

Comment: Since one line is returning a modification of `AIRLINE_OPTION`, and the other is returning a modification of `AIRLINES_PARAM`, I suspect there's no way to do this in one command - they're two completely separate commands with separate inputs and separate outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

```
IFS=/ read -r -a LIST <<< "${AIRLINE_OPTION//-A /}"
```

This places the output from the parameter substitution `${AIRLINE_OPTION//-A /}` into a "here-string" and uses the bash `read` built-in to parse this into an array. Splitting by `/` is achieved by setting the value of `IFS` to `/` for the `read` command.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, for example, you can create an array and store it in `LIST` variable:

```
$ LIST=($(awk -F"[\/ ]" '{print $2,$3}' <<< "-A AA/BB"))
```

Result:

```
$ echo ${LIST[0]}
AA
$ echo ${LIST[1]}
BB
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"[\/ ]"` defines two possible field separators: a space or a slash `/`.
- `'{print $2$3}'` prints the 2nd and 3rd fields based on those separators.

Comment: That looks better, now I can +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
LIST=( $(IFS=/; for x in ${AIRLINE_OPTION#-A }; do printf "$x "; done) )
```

This is a portable solution, but if your `read` supports `-a` and you don't mind portability then you should go for @1_CR's solution.